# I cant find the module TKinter custom button

Tags: tkinter

I have been searching for tkinter_custom button which is used to create custom buttons. This is the link to the github example + images
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/GuitarTuner/tree/master/documentation
but i can't seem to download it
PIP says ---
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter_custom_button (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter_custom_button

Answer (score 2):

I may not be understanding the question but that does not appear to be a valid PIP package. It's just a github repo, you can clone it and then import the TkinterCustomButton class into your project file.

```
git clone https://github.com/TomSchimansky/GuitarTuner.git
```

You'll find the button class here:

```
GuitarTuner/documentation/tkinter_custom_button.py
```